# REST collection entity with different schema

Tags: rest

Suppose we have the collection `/ads/`
And the entity structure of that collection is:

`{"make": "Audi", "model": "A4"}`

So my question is: What to do if i want to represent same entity in a different form. For example:

`{"aggr": "Audi A4"}`

Should it be the same uri just with a different query param? /ads/?schema=aggr

Or a new resource?

`/aggr?resource=ads`

Comment: '/ads/' and '/ads/?schema=aggr' already are two different resources.  Query parameters are part of the resource identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might use the same resource and represent different schemas based on an Accept header parameter.

A request to `/ads` with `Accept: application/json` would return `{"make": "Audi", "model": "A4"}`, if that is your default schema.

A request to `/ads` with `Accept: application/json; schema=aggr` would return `{"aggr": "Audi A4"}`.

Answer (score 1):

Your resource doesn't change, only its representation. In rest principles, you should use hypermedia for that, with a selection by request header:

```
Accept: application/vnd.api.adsrepresentation1+json;
Accept: application/vnd.api.adsrepresentation2+json;
```